# Creating a togglable CKEditor in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ckeditor

I am trying to create an inline CKEditor view in ember, which can be toggled on or off by the user using an "edit" button.  The idea is that certain users have permission to edit content, so they have the option of clicking an "Edit" button which changes the `<blockquote>` element into a CKeditor instance.  Clicking "Save" should deactivate the editor and restore the original element.  I have it half working with the following code, but the problem is that clicking "Edit" a second time does not recreate the editor, it just sets `contenteditable` on the `<blockquote>`.

```
App.CkEditor = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'blockquote',
    attributeBindings: ['contenteditable'],

    value: '',
    editor: null,
    enabled: false,

    contenteditable: function() {
        if (this.get('enabled')) {
            return 'true';
        } else {
            return 'false';
        }
    }.property('tagName', 'enabled'),

    enabledObserver: function() {
        var editor = this.get('editor');
        if (this.get('enabled') && Ember.isNone(editor)) {
            this.createElement();
        } else if (!this.get('enabled') && !Ember.isNone(editor)) {
            editor.destroy();
            this.createElement();
        }
    }.observes('enabled'),

    createElement: function() {
        if (this.get('enabled')) {
            // Create a CKEDitor
            var configOption = this.get('configOptions')[this.get('config')];
            var _this = this;

            CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
            this.$().ckeditor(function(element) {
                var editor = $(element).ckeditor().editor;
                _this.set('editor', editor);
                editor.setData(_this.get('value'));
                editor.on('change', function(event) {
                    if (editor.checkDirty()) {
                        _this.set('value', editor.getData());
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            // Just create a basic element
            this.$().html(this.get('value'));
        }
    },

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.createElement();
    }
});
```